# gather character from line1 with character from line 2

Tags: vim

I have two lines in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) editor as you can see below

```
3  àáâ
4  aaa
```

Based on these two lines, I'd like to get the result below

```
'à' => 'a',
'á' => 'a',
'â' => 'a',
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have repetitive tasks to do, you can record a macro.

For example here,

`qajxkphi'`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`la' => '`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`la',`<kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>`q`

Explanations:

- `qa` : start recording macro `a`
- `jxkp`: go down one line, erase-copy one character, go up, print it
- `hi'`<kbd>Esc</kbd> : go left, insert one `'`, go back to normal mode
- `la' => ',`<kbd>Esc</kbd> : go right, append after the current character `' => '`, go back to normal mode
- `la'`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>  : go right, append `',` and a newline, and go back to normal mode.
- `q` : stop recording

To use the macro (and confirm that it works), place yourself on the first character and press `@a`. The result is:

```
'à' => 'a',
áâ
aa
```

and you're in the second line. Press `2@a` to execute the macro twice and get:

```
'à' => 'a',
'á' => 'a',
'â' => 'a',
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the below 3 `map`-pings in your `~/.exrc` file and then load the file in `vi|vim|gvim` you wanted edited. Bring the cursor anywhere on the line where you want the transformation, and just depress the `Q` key in `ESC` mode of `vi` and this `recursive` `macro` will do the rest.
N.B.: the `^M` are not to be literally and they are inserted into the file by pressing the following keycombo: `<Ctrl><V> <Ctrl><M>`

```
:map q :s/./&\r/^M
:map v :s/\(.\) \(.\)/'\1' => '\2',/^M
:map Q :/^^M-q+q-dd-P-Jv+Q
```